# Why is my auto-fill formula from a macro being modified?

Tags: excel, vba, macros, formula, autofill

I have used the following solution to auto fill a formula from  a macro.

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238125/loop-paste-formula-until-next-cell-in-range-is-empty/41154346#41154346)

The code called for the following line:

```
Sub FillData()
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Range([a1], [a1].End(xlDown))
If Not (rng1.Rows.Count = Rows.Count And Len([a1].Value) = 0) Then rng1.Offset(0, 3).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC2"
End Sub
```

Using this example I created the following code piece:

```
If Not (rng1.Rows.Count = Rows.Count And Len([a1].Value) = 0) Then rng1.Offset(1, 4).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC1,'My Excel Tab name'!A:D,4,FALSE)"
```

However the formula which ends up in the cells does have brackets around the D in A:D and looks like this:

```
=VLOOKUP($A3,'SubstationsPJM-New'!A:(D),4,FALSE)
```

What do I do wrong here?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're not using `R1C1` references in your formula.

You need to replace `'My Excel Tab name'!A:D` with the `R1C1` equivalent which would be `'My Excel Tab name'!C1:C4` (Columns 1 to 4) so your formula should look like this:

```
"=VLOOKUP(RC1,'My Excel Tab name'!C1:C4,4,FALSE)"
```

Comment: No problem, if you're satisfied with this answer you can mark it correct to show that the question has been answered correctly.